# Subtraction of 2 numbers from Firebase and display it on the app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Image of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8RDu.png)

[image: Image of Firebase]

I am trying to subtract (mathematics subtraction) 2 string values which I am getting from the Firebase and i want it to be displayed at my ListTile (Under Total In Service). The values are: -

1. Total Equipment (80.0)
2. Total OOS (20.0)

and I should get Total In Service = 60.0.

Instead I get a String value displayed as Total In Service: 80.0 - 20.0.

Here are the codes: -

```
Row(
children: const [
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  ),
],
```

),
Row(children: [
Expanded(
child: SizedBox(
height: 400.0,
child: FutureBuilder(
future: users.doc(widget.value2).get(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
return const CircularProgressIndicator();
}

```
              Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!
                  .data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

              return ListView(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                      title: const Text('Comments:'),
                      subtitle:
                          Text('${data['Comments']}'),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _updateComments();
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  ListTile(
                      title: const Text(
                          'Total Equipment:'),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          '${data['Total Equipment']}'),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _updateTotalEquipment();
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  ListTile(
                      title: const Text('Total OOS'),
                      subtitle:
                          Text('${data['Total OOS']}'),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.edit),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _updateTotalOOS();
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  ListTile(
                    title:
                        const Text('Total In Service'),
                    subtitle: Text(
/*  */                'Total In Service: ${data['Total Equipment']} - ${data['Total OOS']}'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this in your code:

```
'Total In Service: ${data['Total Equipment']} - ${data['Total OOS']}'
```

So you have a single with two template literals in there, and then output the result string, which indeed will lead to what you see.

If you want to output the result of the subtraction, you need to have a single template literal with the subtraction in there. So:

```
'Total In Service: ${data['Total Equipment'] - data['Total OOS']}'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Simple solution but slipped by mind.